# how to get the value of a node in xsl based on a value from other node

Tags: xml, xslt

How do I get the the index of the string that is provided inside node "s" and find the corresponding index value based on the name in the "strings" node?

This is my XSL template:

```
 <xsl:template match="norm" >
     <xsl:variable name="name" select="@string" />
     <xsl:value-of select="/s/string/@name=$name/@index"/>,
 </xsl:template>
```

This is a fragment from my source XML:

```
<s name="main">
    <norm string="back-slash"/>
    <norm string="open-braces" />
    <norm string="close-braces" />
</s>
<strings  name="consts">
  <string name="back-slash" val="\\" index="0"/>
  <string name="close-braces" val="]" index="2"/>
  <string name="remove-null" val="null" index="3" /> 
</strings>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//strings/string[@name=$name]/@index" />
```

The big thing you did wrong was you used `/` instead of `[` and `]` to enclose your conditional `@name=$name`.

You also used `/s` when you want `//strings`. There is no `s/string` element.

Comment: thanks i just need to add "//strings" and it started working. thanks a lot

Comment: @user2421350 Thanks for the feedback, I have updated my answer. It was a copy and paste error from my test environment.

Answer (score 1):

I would define a key `<xsl:key name="s" match="strings/string" use="@name"/>` and then use `<xsl:value-of select="key('s', @string)/@index"/>` in the template.